# How to rearrange $(pgh_b)(s^2)-(pgh_t)(s^2)$ to $(pg)(s^2)(h_b-h_t)$

Tags: linear-algebra

can someone please show me the steps to go from this

$$ (pgh_b)(s^2)-(pgh_t)(s^2) $$

to this

$$ (pg)(s^2)(h_b-h_t) $$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(pgh_b)(s^2)-(pgh_t)(s^2)$$
$$= (pg)(h_b)(s^2)-(pg)(h_t)(s^2)$$
Now do a rearrangement of the terms
$$= (pg)(s^2)(h_b)-(pg)(s^2)(h_t)$$
and you can see, by factorization
$$= (pgs^2)(h_b)-(pgs^2)(h_t)$$
And finally you get
$$= (pgs^2)(h_b-h_t) = (pg)(s^2)(h_b-h_t)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm quite confused you went from $(pgs^2)(h_b)-(pgs^2)(h_t)$ to $(pgs^2)(h_b-h_t)$. How did the 2nd $(pgs^2)$ get taken out of the equation?

Comment: It's factorization. We take out the common factor of both terms $(pgs^2)$, and then bring $h_b$ and $h_t$ terms together.

Comment: Ah yeh. Got it. Thanks a million.